# Python how to separate punctuation from text

Tags: python, regex

So I want to separate group of punctuation from the text with spaces.

```
my_text = "!where??and!!or$$then:)"
```

I want to have a `! where ?? and !! or $$ then :)` as a result.

I wanted something like in Javascript, where you can use `$1` to get your matching string. What I have tried so far:

```
my_matches = re.findall('[!"\$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;=#@?\[\\\]^_`{|}~]*', my_text)
```

Here my_matches is empty so I had to delete `\\\` from the expression:

```
my_matches = re.findall('[!"\$%&\'()*+,\-.\/:;=#@?\^_`{|}~]*', my_text)
```

I have this result:

```
['!', '', '', '', '', '', '??', '', '', '', '!!', '', '', '$$', '', '', '', '',
':)', '']
```

So I delete all the redundant entry like this:

```
my_matches_distinct = list(set(my_matches))
```

And I have a better result:

```
['', '??', ':)', '$$', '!', '!!']
```

Then I replace every match by himself and space:

```
for match in my_matches:
if match != '':
    my_text = re.sub(match, ' ' + match + ' ', my_text)
```

And of course it's not working ! I tried to cast the match as a string, but it's not working either... When I try to put directly the string to replace it's working though.

But I think I'm not doing it right, because I will have problems with '!' et '!!' right?

Thanks :)

Comment: It is recommended to use raw string literals when defining a regex pattern. Besides, do not escape arbitrary symbols inside a character class, only ``\`` must be always escaped, and others can be placed so that they do not need escaping. Also, your regex matches an empty string - and it does - due to `*`. Replace with `+` quantifier.

Comment: If you want to remove these symbols from your string, why use `re.findall` at all?

Comment: Because I want to put space in front and after these group of symbol and I don't know how to store that ?

Comment: Not sure what you need, please post the expected result. If you want `! where ?? and !! or $$ then :)`, use `print(re.sub(r'[]!"$%&\'()*+,./:;=#@?[\\^_\`{|}~-]+', r' \g<0> ', my_text).strip())`. See https://ideone.com/8BGDgN.

Comment: i have posted the expected result :) and this is exactly what I needed ! sorry i'm so bad with regex. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, I could not see it due to formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use raw string literals when defining a regex pattern. Besides, do not escape arbitrary symbols inside a character class, only `\` must be always escaped, and others can be placed so that they do not need escaping. Also, your regex matches an empty string - and it does - due to `*`. Replace with `+` quantifier. Besides, if you want to remove these symbols from your string, use `re.sub` directly.

```py
import re
my_text = "!where??and!!or$$then:)"
print(re.sub(r'[]!"$%&\'()*+,./:;=#@?[\\^_`{|}~-]+', r' \g<0> ', my_text).strip())
# => ! where ?? and !! or $$ then :)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8BGDgN)

**Details**: The `` []!"$%&'()*+,./:;=#@?[\^_`{|}~-]+ `` matches any 1+ symbols from the set (note that only `\` is escaped here since `-` is used at the end, and `]` at the start of the class), and the replacement inserts a space  + the whole match (the `\g<0>` is the backreference to the whole match) and a space. And `.strip()` will remove leading/trailing whitespace after the regex finishes processing the string.

**`string.punctuation` NOTE**

Those who think that they can use `f"[{string.punctuation}]+"` make a mistake because this won't match `\`. Why? Because the resulting pattern looks like `` [!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]+ `` and the `\]` part does not match a backslash or `]`, it only matches a `]` since the `\` escapes the `]` char.

If you plan to use `string.punctuation`, you need to escape `]` and `\` (it would be also correct to escape `-` and `^` as these are the only special chars inside square brackets, but in this case, it would be redundant):

```py
from string import punctuation
my_text = "!where??and!!or$$then:)"
pattern = "[" + punctuation.replace('\\','\\\\').replace(']', r'\]') + "]+"
print(re.sub(pattern, r' \g<0> ', my_text).strip())
# => ! where ?? and !! or $$ then :)
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/nDjkZp).

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for my clumsy question :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `sub()` method in `re` library. You can do this as follows,

```
import re
str = '!where??and!!or$$then:)'
print re.sub(r'([!@#%\^&\*\(\):;"\',\./\\]+)', r' \1 ', str).strip()
```

I hope this code should solve your problem. If you are obvious with `regex` then the regex part is not a big deal. Just it is to use the right function.

Hope this helps! Please comment if you have any queries. :)

---

References:

[Python re library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)